# non systematic bug when my application start (call stack joined in an attached file)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

My application don't start 1% of time for a unknow reason.

Under Microsoft Visual Studio I get the bug in DEBUG mode, below it's the call stack when the problem appear :
[Call stack](http://a.yfrog.com/img736/3537/2u4u.png)

I don't know if this call stack can be exploited, and if it can give some clues about the problem.

I don't understand why the call stack look like this, it seems I can't find where the program bug in my source code

Thanks for any advices

Comment: 1% as ' well, almost never but sometimes ' or really statistically 1/100 cases fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an exception occures in the DLL startup code. Make sure no exception is thrown from the constructors of statically declared object in your DLL. Objects that are declared outside functions are initialized by the RTL (eg. their constructors are being called). Such contructors may not throw or cause exceptions.

Comment: so If RTL initialize an object which throw an excpetion, the call stack doesn't show me the line of my source which throw this excpetion ?

Comment: Maybe the exception occures at a point where no debug information is present, otherwise, the debugger would break. Try setting the debugger to break on all exception types, even if those exceptions are 'handled' somewhere. Consult the Debug/exception menu to find out how this is done in your specific debugger program (MSVC).